# Removing clusters of duplicates in a query resultset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query returning the following results:

```
db=# SELECT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
db-#  FROM table_1 As t1, table_2 As t2
db-#  WHERE ST_DWithin(t2.lonlat, t1.lonlat, t2.range)
db-#  ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id, ST_Distance(t2.lonlat, t1.lonlat);
  id1  | id2  
-------+------
  4499 | 1118
  4500 | 1118
  4501 | 1119
  4502 | 1119
  4503 | 1118
  4504 | 1118
  4505 | 1119
  4506 | 1119
  4507 | 1118
  4508 | 1118
  4510 | 1118
  4511 | 1118
  4514 | 1117
  4515 | 1117
  4518 | 1117
  4519 | 1117
  4522 | 1117
  4523 | 1117
  4603 | 1116
  4604 | 1116
  4607 | 1116
```

And I want the resultset to look like this:

```
  id1  | id2  
-------+------
  4499 | 1118
  4501 | 1119
  4503 | 1118
  4505 | 1119
  4507 | 1118
  4514 | 1117
  4603 | 1116
```

Essentially, in the results, the query is returning duplicates of `id2`, but it's ok that `id2` occurs many times in the results, but it's *not* ok if `id2` is duplicated in clusters.

The use case here is that `id1` represents the ID of a table of GPS positions, while `id2` represents a table of waypoints, and I want to have a query that returns the closest passing point to any waypoint (so if waypoint #1118 is passed, then it cannot be passed again until another waypoint is passed).

Is there a way to make this happen using Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, but rather subtle.  In this case, you only want the rows where the previous row has a different `id2`.  That suggests using `LAG()`:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM (SELECT tt.*, LAG(id2) OVER (ORDER BY id1, id2, dist) as prev_id2
      FROM (SELECT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2,
                   ST_Distance(t2.lonlat, t1.lonlat) as dist
            FROM table_1 t1 JOIN
                 table_2 t2
                 ON ST_DWithin(t2.lonlat, t1.lonlat, t2.range)
           ) tt
     ) tt
WHERE prev_id2 is distinct from id2
ORDER BY id1, id2, dist;
```

Note:  I think the logic as presented could be simplified because `id1` seems unique.  Hence the distance calculation seems entirely superfluous.  I left that logic in because it might be relevant in your actual query.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - a couple notes on my end: 1. `id1` is indeed unique; 2. The distance calculation is important, because I am looking to get the *closest* passing point, and not the first passing point - so if the range to a waypoint (table_2) is 10 metres, for example, then the GPS (table_1) may have records at distances: 10m, then 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 7, 9, and I want the record in table_1 where the distance is 1m from the waypoint. Does that affect your answer at all?

Comment: @AlexCrooks . . . You are ordering by `id1, id2`.  I don't think the distance is every taken into account.  In any case, the `order by` in the `lag()` should match whatever `order by` you really want.